# A case where CSS seems to lose control of the screen layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When writing HTML, I often find it handy to use **pre** tags whenever I want to include snippets of source code. **pre** tags are great, because they tell the browser to preserve all whitespace, including indentation, and not to do line wrapping. I use jQuery Chili to do the highlighting and it requires that I use a **code** tag inside the **pre** tag to process and highlight the snippet.

When I tried to highlight a code snippet containing a long paragraph «*Loren ipsum ... Pellente conque.*» with jQuery Chili, it causes the display of the page on the screen **to extend far beyond the edge of the viewport thus generating horizontal scroll bars** . The browser goes **mad** and the **layout of the page is completely broken**.

jQuery Chili process this paragraph as follows (using "html" as a language):

```
<span class="html__tag_start"><p></span>Lorem&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;dolor&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet,&nbsp;consectetur&nbsp;adipiscing&nbsp;elit.&nbsp;Sed&nbsp;non&nbsp;risus.&nbsp;Suspendisse&nbsp;lectus&nbsp;tortor,&nbsp;dignissim&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet,&nbsp;adipiscing&nbsp;nec,&nbsp;ultricies&nbsp;sed,&nbsp;dolor.&nbsp;Cras&nbsp;elementum&nbsp;ultrices&nbsp;diam.&nbsp;Maecenas&nbsp;ligula&nbsp;massa,&nbsp;varius&nbsp;a,&nbsp;semper&nbsp;congue,&nbsp;euismod&nbsp;non,&nbsp;mi.&nbsp;Proin&nbsp;porttitor,&nbsp;orci&nbsp;nec&nbsp;nonummy&nbsp;molestie,&nbsp;enim&nbsp;est&nbsp;eleifend&nbsp;mi,&nbsp;non&nbsp;fermentum&nbsp;diam&nbsp;nisl&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;erat.&nbsp;Duis&nbsp;semper.&nbsp;Duis&nbsp;arcu&nbsp;massa,&nbsp;scelerisque&nbsp;vitae,&nbsp;consequat&nbsp;in,&nbsp;pretium&nbsp;a,&nbsp;enim.&nbsp;Pellentesque&nbsp;congue.<span class="html__tag_end"></p></span>
```

It puts highlighting span tags on key language elements like `<p>` at the beginning and `</p>` at the end and **replaces every normal space of the text in-between by a non-breaking space**. **It's really wide content!**

This mixture of live span tags surrounding the long word causes the browser to display a broken layout despites the use of various **CSS tricks** like  `overflow:auto;`, `white-space: pre-wrap;` or `word-wrap: break-word;`. I use the CSS Table Model for the layout of the site: the snippet is therefore located within a DIV with `display:table-cell;`. Even a style such as body `{max-width: 1000px !important;}` does not resist!

***This happens only when the snippet is located inside a site structured by the CSS Table Model***. If I put the same snippet in the body tag of a test program without any DIV or within a DIV with `display:block;`, **the layout is preserved**. When the DIV is styled as `display:table;`, the **layout breaks away**. Check it with http://jsfiddle.net/gtro/Ly8a2wa8/6/.

In the case under investigation, there must be a difference in the action resulting from the display (block or table): "block" is OK whereas "table" breaks the layout.

The explanation of this phenomenon is beyond my knowledge of Web programming. Can anybody tell me why it happens?

**Hint**

[7 Oct 14] - Table Layouts vs. Div Layouts: From Hell to… Hell? [http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/] gave me a hint: « **tables don’t break when the content is too wide** ». Is it so for the DIVs?

**Solution**

[8 Oct 14] - I observed that the layout **breaks out** when the display property is set to *table* and the *max-width* property of the pre tag is set in percentage as it was when I submitted this question. On the other hand, if this *max-width* is set to a **fixed number of pixels**, the layout is **preserved**. The problem with fixing the *max-width* property in the CSS is that we don't know ahead of time what the dimentions of the client screen will be. Therefore, it requires some Javascript (or jQuery) to fix this. Though I'm not a fan of applying CSS through JavaScript, I have used this

```
$("pre").css('max-width', $("body").width());
```

after DOM load and the layout is **preserved**. Problem solved.

However, it does not tell me why changing the display property of the container DIV from *block* to *table* causes the **break out of the layout**. I am not knowledgeable enough in the W3C specifications to find this by myself. This question remains open.

Comment: Post the code in a jsfiddle... Give us a link to your site.. Or something we can look at.

Comment: I modified the question and added a reference to a jsFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/gtro/Ly8a2wa8/6/] that I have developed last night. @Nicholas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the width with `max-width` which does not apply to table rows (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width). Since you don't define any widths for your table, the combination of the table with the `li` is what is causing the row to become so wide.

If you want to continue using a table you will need to define a `width` for the table or a `max-width` for `code li`.

Comment: The idea of using the max-width property of the li tag resolves the problem when line-numbering is on (the code is wrapped in an ol tag and each line in a  li tag. Sadly, it does not work when line-numbering is off since no ol nor li tags are produced by the highlighter.